# Marine Acoustician Interview Advice

Tags: career, jobs

I have an interview for a marine acoustician position approaching, and I was wondering if anyone has any advice or suggestions as to what questions may be asked? I recently graduated with a degree in marine science and this is my first interview post - college, so I do not have much interview experience. I aspire to pursue the field of marine bioacoustics, so this is a dream job and any advice is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

I assume you have sufficient knowledge on acoustics /sound propagation in water.

A lot of questions relate to the work the new employer is doing and what essential/desirable knowledge is mentioned in the announcement. Definitely you should understand how the essential qualifications relate to the business of the employer but the desirable qualifications will make the difference.

If you do your homework and study the employer, you should be prepared to explain convincingly how you fit into the work the team is doing.

I know, this all is common sense, but, IMHO, more important than technical details.

Answer (score 5):

Congratulations on your interview opportunity!

To echo what WMXZ said, I would imagine many of the questions will be more general for any research-type job than specific to acoustics. I would prepare for questions about your work experience in research, how you work independently and as part of a team, experience you have data curation, analysis, and writing (manuscripts or reports). I would also expect questions about how you may handle specific situations (problem solving, navigating work relationships, asking for help, etc).

It is very good to be specific when answering interview questions - so, for example, if your best strength is your attention to detail - don't just say that but also give an example of how you have implemented that in the past with a concrete example from your school work, independent research, or a job. It doesn't necessarily have to be an example from acoustics research, but examples like that are usually more telling about a candidate than just stating "I'm good at X and Y."

My only bit of acoustics-specific advice would be that you probably already shared what programs you are familiar with on your application materials, but be prepared to list those again. And, if you are asked about a program you have not used yet, you can just be honest about how you did learn other new programs and how that experience will likely help you learn any additional ones you need. You may not enter the job with every skill in acoustics you need right away, but conveying your enthusiasm and ability to learn new things can still make you a good candidate.

Good luck!